# Is diffraction encoded in the wave equation?

Tags: waves

In other words is it possible to set conditions and constraints directly in the classic wave PDE to model say a single slit diffraction?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, the wave equation has everything except the boundary conditions, and that you always have to do manually anyway.  So to do a single or double slit, you need some way to tell the wave equation that the slit is there, but after that, it's all the wave equation.